# Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and assume that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $|x|< \epsilon$. Prove that $x = 0$. Use a proof by contradiction.

Tags: proof-writing

I appreciate any help you can give me in solving this problem.

Comment: Hint: What about $\epsilon=|x|$?

Comment: The body of the Question is intended to allow a self-contained problem statement.  Relying on the title alone to bear this burden invites omission of setup and other context, leading to confusion for Readers.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\neq0$ and take $\epsilon=\frac{\vert x\vert}{2}$. Then you see that $\vert x\vert\ge\epsilon$ (and even $>$).

Hence $x=0$.